# Carrierwave undefined method `avatar_changed?' for User

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, carrierwave

I use carrierwave gem for uploading image.I use attr_accessor: avatar in my model.I don't want to create the database column. I can store avatar in the particular directory.But when i update_attribute for some other field, i am getting undefined method `undefined method`avatar_changed?' for User`. Am i missing anything here? Help me to solve this.
This is my User model

```
 attr_accessor: avatar
 mount_uploader: avatar, AvatarUploader

AvatarUploader < IconBase
  DIEMENSIONS=[120,120]

  def filename
    "avatar.png"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use 
`mount_uploader: avatar, AvatarUploader`
you should create database columns. IF you do not want to add columns, you should not mount an Uploader, but rather work with things like that:

```
uploader = AvatarUploader.new
uploader.store!(my_file)
uploader.retrieve_from_store!('my_file.png')
```

Comment: Be sure you have executed all your migrations! `rake db:migrate`